# Safe to to store data in the keychain?

Tags: ios, macos, keychain

I'm developing an application for iOS and macOS, and I needed to store a hash value in the keychain. I noticed from a couple of different places including Apple, that a user can reset a keychain or create a new one. If they reset this will it also remove items that my application has saved in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MacOS users can see keychain values, modify them and delete them using the keychain utility.  They can also replace the current keychain with a new, empty, keychain but this would be very disruptive to the user as every stored password and other items such as certificates would now be in th sold keychain file which is not accessible to applications.

On iOS there is no direct keychain access on a non-jail broken device, but as of 10.3 if an app is deleted, its keychain items are removed.

Comment: On `macOS` when a keychain is "reset" the behavior is to revert to the factory defaults and create a new empty "login" keychain. The current keychain is moved aside, but not deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified this, but the result is the same; old keychain items are not available to applications

Comment: Correct, although it's only a matter of doing `Add Keychain...` to add items back. I'm surprised `iOS` doesn't have that ability; seems like a disaster in the making.

Comment: iOS is totally sandboxed. The user can't add or remove items from the keychain or create a new keychain.